# Does async requests impacts UI thread performance

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, google-chrome-devtools, electron, axios

From attached timeline recorded from an Electron App, is it possible that the async requests block/impact UI thread? Is there any solution for this?

[image]

Question updated.

Comment: Only if the UI thread waits for the requests to be served, which then is not the async requests themselves doing the blocking.  A thread can be **blocked** only by code running *in* that thread.  If, on the other hand, you're asking whether async requests can impact UI performance, then that's an altogether different question.

Comment: @JohnBollinger, thanks for your clear explanation, as far as I know from the src, UI thread is not waiting the axios response, but the gray "long frame" which indicates CPU Idle always shows up after handled the "mousedown" event and dispatched action to make request from React Components. So I'm guessing if it could be related. Any ideas about the "Idle Janks"? or are async requests impacts UI performance? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Use `defer` instead of `async`.  If `async` scripts get downloaded first, they can still block rendering since they will get executed before non-async scripts.  You can read a much more in depth examination about this here: http://calendar.perfplanet.com/2016/prefer-defer-over-async/